# New to Ruby, trouble with if and gets function

Tags: ruby, if-statement

```
puts "The road splits, do you go left or right?"

choice = gets
if choice == 'right'
  puts "You walk right"
elsif choice == 'left'
  puts "You walk left"
else
  puts "Not a valid choice"
  puts choice
  puts choice.class
end
```

No matter what I type it always returns false. I tried the same thing with changing 'right' and 'left' to 1 and 2, and then it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string returned by `gets` will include an "\n" at the end unless you're a the end of the file.

Use `String#chomp` (`choice = gets.chomp`) to get rid of it.

If you're not sure what's going on, use `p` to print out some debugging info, e.g.: 
`p choice`
Unlike puts, it returns the printed expression so you can chain it and it runs `.inspect` on it before printing it, allowing you to see the representation.  `puts` does a little bit of magic too -- namely that it only doesn't add a newline if its argument already ends with one. This trick that `puts` does might have made finding the source of your problem a little bit more difficult.

Comment: Thanks, added the .chomp after gets and if worked. That p is pretty useful.